# The entering data is different from posting data and it is posting null values instead of the entering data, How do i address this?

Tags: c#, database, rest, entity-framework-core, swagger

The main issue is that the entering data array is not posted correctly and it was not passed so instead it passes null values, how can i post entering data instead of the to post data.. and i have checked all endpoints and it is correct the enpoint is https://localhost:7072/api/Client

[image]

As you can see on the console it is post 404 not found api error how do i go about this code it looks like it passed the data but it is null values instead of the entering data

this is my code

```
const handleSaveButtonClick = () => {


// Data validation and parsing
const parsedClientId = parseInt(ClientId);
const parsedClientName = ClientName;
const parsedCompleteAddress = CompleteAddress;
const parsedContactNumber = parseInt(ContactNumber);
const parsedBusiness = Business;
const parsedPrincipalAmount = parseFloat(PrincipalAmount);
const parsedLoanTerm= parseInt(LoanTerm);
const parsedLoanCycle= parseInt(LoanCycle);
const parsedLoanBalance= parseFloat(LoanBalance);
const parsedArrearsAmount= parseFloat(ArrearsAmount);
const DateGrantedString = DateGranted instanceof Date ? DateGranted.toISOString() : '';
const MaturityDateString = MaturityDate instanceof Date ? MaturityDate.toISOString() : '';    
const LastTransactionDateString = LastTransactionDate instanceof Date ? LastTransactionDate.toISOString() : '';    
const parsedLoanStatus= LoanStatus;
const parsedCBUBalance= parseFloat(CBUBalance);
const parsedMyIponBalance= parseFloat(MyIponBalance);
const parsedTrustStaff= TrustStaff;

// Construct payload for the post request
const payload = {
  
  ClientId: parsedClientId,
  ClientName: ClientName,
  CompleteAddress: parsedCompleteAddress,
  ContactNumber: parsedContactNumber,
  Business: parsedBusiness,
  PrincipalAmount: parsedPrincipalAmount,
  LoanTerm: parsedLoanTerm,
  LoanCycle: parsedLoanCycle,
  LoanBalance: parsedLoanBalance,
  ArrearsAmount: parsedArrearsAmount,
  DateGranted: DateGrantedString,
  MaturityDate: MaturityDateString,
  LastTransactionDate: LastTransactionDateString,
  LoanStatus: LoanStatus,
  CBUBalance: parsedCBUBalance,
  MyIponBalance: parsedMyIponBalance,
  TrustStaff: parsedTrustStaff,
  // ... continue with other client information fields
};



// Perform the post request
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Client', payload)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log('Success: You\'ve just added a new Delinquent Account.');
      setSuccessMessage('You\'ve just added a new Delinquent Account.');
      setIsOpen(true); // Show the success modal
      navigate(`/tool`);
    }
    console.log('Payload:', payload);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('API Error:', error);
    setErrorMessage('An error occurred while saving the data. Please try again later.');
    setIsOpen(false);
  });
```

};

```
const handleSaveButtonLeave = (event) => {
const parsedClientId = parseInt(ClientId);
const parsedClientName = ClientName;
const parsedCompleteAddress = CompleteAddress;
const parsedContactNumber = parseInt(ContactNumber);
const parsedBusiness = Business;
const parsedPrincipalAmount = parseInt(PrincipalAmount);
const parsedLoanTerm= parseInt(LoanTerm);
const parsedLoanCycle= parseInt(LoanCycle);
const parsedLoanBalance= parseInt(LoanBalance);
const parsedArrearsAmount= parseInt(ArrearsAmount);
const DateGrantedString = DateGranted instanceof Date ? DateGranted.toISOString() : '';
const MaturityDateString = MaturityDate instanceof Date ? MaturityDate.toISOString() : '';    
const LastTransactionDateString = LastTransactionDate instanceof Date ? LastTransactionDate.toISOString() : '';    
const parsedLoanStatus= LoanStatus;
const parsedCBUBalance= parseInt(CBUBalance);
const parsedMyIponBalance= parseInt(MyIponBalance);
const parsedTrustStaff= parseInt(TrustStaff);


send({
  type: "POST_DATA",
  postData: {
    client: {
    
      ClientId: parsedClientId,
      ClientName: ClientName,
      CompleteAddress: CompleteAddress,
      ContactNumber: parsedContactNumber,
      Business: Business,
      PrincipalAmount: parsedPrincipalAmount,
      LoanTerm: parsedLoanTerm,
      LoanCycle: parsedLoanCycle,
      LoanBalance: parsedLoanBalance,
      ArrearsAmount: parsedArrearsAmount,
      DateGranted: DateGranted,
      MaturityDate: MaturityDate,   
      LastTransactionDate: LastTransactionDate,   
      LoanStatus: LoanStatus,
      CBUBalance: parsedCBUBalance,
      MyIponBalance: parsedMyIponBalance,
      TrustStaff: TrustStaff,
    },
  },
});
```

};

```
postingData: {
  invoke: {
    src: (context, event) => POST_REQUEST("/api/Client", event.postData),

    onDone: {
      target: "fetchingData",
      actions: [
        assign({
          client: (_, event) => {
            if (event && event.data) {
              console.log("To post:", event.data);
              const responseData = event.data.data;
              return responseData;
            }
            return [];
          },
        }),
        (context, event) => {
          console.log("Success:", context.client);
        },
      ],
    },

    onError: {
      target: "error",
      actions: [
        assign({
          errorMessage: (_, event) => {
            const error: AxiosError = event.data;

            switch (error.response?.status) {
              case 500:
                return "Server error. Please try again later.";

              default:
                console.error("Error:", error); // Print the error details to console
                return `${error.message}. Please try again later.`;
            }
          },
        }),
        (context, event) => {
          console.error("Error occurred while posting data:", event);
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  entry: (context, event) => {
    event.postData.client.ClientId = event.postData.client.ClientId;
    event.postData.client.ClientName = event.postData.client.ClientName;
    event.postData.client.CompleteAddress = event.postData.client.CompleteAddress;
    event.postData.client.ContactNumber = event.postData.client.ContactNumber;
    event.postData.client.Business = event.postData.client.Business;
    event.postData.client.PrincipalAmount = event.postData.client.PrincipalAmount;
    event.postData.client.LoanTerm = event.postData.client.LoanTerm;
    event.postData.client.LoanCycle = event.postData.client.LoanCycle;
    event.postData.client.LoanBalance = event.postData.client.LoanBalance;
    event.postData.client.ArrearsAmount = event.postData.client.ArrearsAmount;
    event.postData.client.DateGranted = event.postData.client.DateGranted;
    event.postData.client.MaturityDate = event.postData.client.MaturityDate;
    event.postData.client.LastTransactionDate = event.postData.client.LastTransactionDate;
    event.postData.client.LoanStatus = event.postData.client.LoanStatus;
    event.postData.client.CBUBalance = event.postData.client.CBUBalance;
    event.postData.client.MyIponBalance = event.postData.client.MyIponBalance;
    event.postData.client.TrustStaff = event.postData.client.TrustStaff;
    console.log("Entering postingData state. Received event:", event);
  },
},
```

Comment: Sound like the request port isn't specify and axios use the client port **3000**, not the API port **7072**.

Comment: yes because it post from the localhost://3000 which is my react app

Comment: it is already on 7072
export const POST_REQUEST = async (endpoint: string, postData: any) => {
  try {
    const token = await GetToken();

    const response = await axios({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:7072",
      method: "POST",
      url: endpoint,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      data: postData,
    });

Comment: The base url is overrided by : `axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Client', payload)`

Comment: Try to replace by `axios.post('api/Client', payload)` to use the default base url or `axios.post('http://localhost:7072/api/Client', payload)` to use absolute url.

Comment: there is a discrepancy between the logged Entering postingData state. Received event: message and the actual data being used to make the POST request, the issue is likely not related to the order of properties. It's more likely that there's an issue with how you're passing the data or how you're processing it in your state machine and POST request logic.

Comment: tried it but it is not working still the same error